# Restricting the host for a MySQL user in a Docker container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am creating a Docker Compose file that includes a PHP service and a MySQL service.  As part of the initialization of the MySQL container, I create a new MySQL user that the PHP container will use to query the database.  Right now, I'm creating the user like this:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypass';
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

This works - my PHP script can successfully query the MySQL database.

However, I'd like to be able to restrict the user to the PHP container, instead of allowing connections from anywhere (`'%'`).  I tried recreated my user like this:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'php' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypass';
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'php';
```

However, when I run the same PHP script, I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'myuser'@'my-docker-container.my-docker-project_my-docker-network'
```

Based on this error, I could theoretically create my user with a host restriction of `my-docker-container.my-docker-project_my-docker-network`.  However, in my specific case, this host string is even longer, and it exceeds the 60 character limit imposed by MySQL.

Is there a way to configure my containers so that my second example (`'myuser'@'php'`) will work?

Here's how my PHP and MySQL services are defined in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
php:
    image: my-php-image
    container_name: my-php-container
    build: ./php
    networks:
        - my-network
mysql:
    image: my-mysql-image
    container_name: my-mysql-container
    build: ./mysql
    volumes:
        - ./mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        - my-mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - my-network
```

Comment: Is ‘my-docker-container.my-docker-project_my-docker-network’ the exact error message? You could update with the real value. It would help.

Comment: @Light.G - It is, but as I mentioned, the real host string is too long - MySQL limits the host to 60 characters, and the string is more than 60 characters.

Comment: Maybe another way provides the equivalent functionality. Create a isolated network for MySQL and only connect the right containers to it. In you case, it’s php container. In docker philosophy, we concern more about which service/container I could reach, not the container running as client. If we must concern client, like your case, we prefer to network isolation, since it’s cheap and easy to deploy in docker world.

Comment: In your php project, did you apply the connection to MySQL with “mysql:3306/db”?